# Add where clause to calculated field in cakephp 3 query

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a query in which I want the name of a company and its employee quantity. The thing is I want to filter this result by some conditions (like `employee_number > 50` etc.). My problem is that, when building the query, I don't know how to filter this result, as the condition is set over a calculated field, so when applying the condition it gives me the below

```
Error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'employee_number' in 'where clause'`.
```

I have been trying different things, but this is what I currently have:

```
$query = $this->Companies->find('all')->where($conditions)->contain(['Users']);
        

$query
   ->select(['Users.name',
   'Company.modified',
   'employee_number' => $query->func()->count('DISTINCT(Employees.id)')])
   ->where('employee_number >' => 50 )
   ->leftJoinWith('Employees', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
       return $query->where(['deleted' => 0]);
   })
   ->group(['Employees.company_id', 'Company.id']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you cannot refer to an aggregate in the `WHERE` clause, as grouping happens afterwards, hence the error, the field `employee_number` doesn't exist when the `WHERE` conditions are being applied, you have to leverage the `HAVING` clause instead.

Depending on the DBMS that you are using you can reference the column from the select list, MySQL for example allows that:

```php
$query
    ->select([
        'Users.name',
        'Company.modified',
        'employee_number' => $query->func()->count('DISTINCT Employees.id')
    ])
    ->leftJoinWith('Employees', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return $query->where(['deleted' => 0]);
    })
    ->group(['Employees.company_id', 'Company.id'])
    ->having(['employee_number >' => 50]);
```

while Postgres for example doesn't, and requires you to repeat the aggregation inside of the `HAVING` clause:

```php
->having(function (
    \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
    \Cake\ORM\Query $query
) {
    return $exp->gt($query->func()->count('DISTINCT Employees.id'), 50);
});
```

ps. using `DISTINCT` should only be necessary when you have for example multiple joins that would result in duplicate joined rows.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Aggregates - Group and Having](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The having clause was what I needed in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was able to filter using my calculated field by adding the `having` clause